# Override <ALT> to toggle menu bar on VS CODE

Tags: visual-studio-code

What I want to achieve is as follows:

1. Disable `ALT` to show menu bar by `toggle-menu-bar` completely.

   -> Potentially map `ALT` to a `NULL` action?
2. Use a different shortcut to `toggle-menu-bar`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 88):

On Ubuntu I needed this two settings in `settings.json` :

```
"window.titleBarStyle": "custom",
"window.customMenuBarAltFocus": false
```

(VS Code restart might be required)

---

Related:

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/84227
- https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_36#_disable-alt-key-focus-of-the-custom-menu-bar

Answer (score 35):

My only solution is to set menu always hidden to prevent interfering with alt-hotkeys. But enabling mnemonics still allows you to reveal it by pressing Alt+F for example.
[image]

Comment: This can also be achieved with 
`"window.menuBarVisibility": "hidden",  "window.enableMenuBarMnemonics": true`
in settings.json. The enableMenuBarMnemonics seem to be the default and hence unnecssary. To access menu, press Alt-F or Alt-E, or Alt-whatever

Comment: Unset checkbox for "Enable Menu Bar Mnemonics" and add your own hotkey to toggle menu - for example, ctrl+q. 
This disables showing menu on alt click completely.

Comment: @budden73 could you turn that into an answer? It is the only correct one I found here i.e. which actually works. Thanks!

Comment: In [VSCodium](https://vscodium.com/) at least, this setting is **a user one, not a profile's!** You might be confused why it doesn't show in intellisense when you're editing the profile's json settings.

Answer (score 9):

I have tried this on Win10, and adding these 3 lines to `settings.json` will work for me, while the latest upvoted answer will make the Menu bar hidden, which is not what we want.

```
"window.titleBarStyle": "custom",
"window.customMenuBarAltFocus": false,
"window.enableMenuBarMnemonics": false,
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm using v1.25.1 and the setting to disable ALT menu selection is `"window.enableMenuBarMnemonics": false`. You can keep the menu visible.

Comment: Nice although it's a shame that ALT still causes the editor to loose focus

Comment: I have this setting disabled, but pressing `ALT` will still toggle and focus the main menu.

Answer (score 5):

This fixed it for me (I'm using Linux)

```
 "window.titleBarStyle": "custom"
```

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to set menu always hidden to prevent interfering with alt-hotkeys. But enabling mnemonics still allows you to reveal it by pressing Alt+F for example.

This can be achieved with "window.menuBarVisibility": "hidden", "window.enableMenuBarMnemonics": true in settings.json. The enableMenuBarMnemonics seem to be the default and hence unnecssary.

To access menu, press Alt-F or Alt-E, or Alt-whatever

This answer originates from [Dmitriy Botov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54320738/9469533)

and [my comment on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48044429/override-alt-to-toggle-menu-bar-on-vs-code/54320738?noredirect=1#comment96136646_54320738)

Answer (score 1):

Just "window.menuBarVisibility": "hidden" works.

Answer (score 1):

As in [Dmitriy Botov answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54320738/7136732), adding those lines

```
"window.customMenuBarAltFocus": false, 
"window.enableMenuBarMnemonics": false,
"window.menuBarVisibility": "hidden",
```

to the config works, but when I toggle the menu bar with e.g. alt+f the menu stays open.
If I use the toggle menu bar command/keybind the setting of `"window.menuBarVisibility": "hidden"` will be changed to `"window.menuBarVisibility": "classic"` and then to `"window.menuBarVisibility": "toggle"` which enables showing the menu bar on alt key again.

However, I'm using the [Settings Cycler](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=hoovercj.vscode-settings-cycler) extension and build a command with it that does the job for me:

**1. in `settings.json` add:**

```
"settings.cycle": [{
        "id": "toggleMenuBar",
        "values":[
            { "window.menuBarVisibility": "hidden" },
            { "window.menuBarVisibility": "visible" }
        ]
      }
    ],
```

**2. Set a keybind for the new command:**

```
{
     "key": "alt+shift+w",
     "command": "settings.cycle.toggleMenuBar",
}
```

This shows the menu bar and removes the "toggle on alt key" functionality when hidden.

**Tested on vscode 1.60.0**

Answer (score 0):

open setting from `File --> Preferences --> Settings` and in `searchBox` type `menu bar`
in Result you can turn off it and whatever you want to do[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ir3NC.png)