# How to disable alt key to focus on File tab in VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my linux version of VS Code, when I press the `Alt` key it focuses on the File tab of the menu bar. Not sure how I made it this way. It wasn't this way before.

How do I disable this?

Comment: Hitting `Alt` key singly will move focus of the window on menu bar. I think it is the default behavior of most `GUI` application in both Linux and Windows, you can try in other application on your desktop. Why do you want to change this? Do you want to use some specific keybinding in fact, or other purposes?

Comment: You said "It wasn't this way before" so what is the behavior of `Alt` your expect before?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48044429/override-alt-to-toggle-menu-bar-on-vs-code This has the answer

Comment: Advise you to write your own answer, or flag this post as a duplicate.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `settings.json`

```
"window.titleBarStyle": "custom",
"window.customMenuBarAltFocus": false
```

Comment: This one simply solves the problem entirely. I think it should be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl-, to open the setting and search for:

> window.enableMenuBarMnemonics

Disable the option.

Or add this to your settings.json file:

> "window.enableMenuBarMnemonics": false,

https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_36#_disable-alt-key-focus-of-the-custom-menu-bar

Comment: It doesn't help on Ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 0):

these settings helped me:

```
"window.titleBarStyle": "custom"
"window.customMenuBarAltFocus": false
"window.enableMenuBarMnemonics": false
"window.menuBarVisibility": "visible"
```

after settings, perhaps you may need to reload the window: `Ctrl+Shift+P` and select `Developer: Reload window`

my OS: Fedora Linux 37 (Workstation Edition), Gnome 43.3